# Create a haskell constructor for a new data type that takes in a function

Tags: haskell, parameters, pattern-matching

I want to create a new data type that can take in a function.
I know this works:

```
foo :: (Int -> Int -> Int)->Int->Int->Int
foo func x y = (func x y) + 100
```

so you can do this:

```
foo (+) 5 8 --output is 113
```

Now I want to do the same thing but to a custom data type like this:

```
data Bar = Bar (Int Int Int) Int Int --This does not compile
```

so I can use it like this:

```
doCalc :: Bar -> Int 
doCalc (Bar func x y) = (func x y) + 100
```

My question is how do I declare the constructor in my data type to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the first argument of `foo` is of type `(Int -> Int -> Int)` - the type of a function that takes two `Int`s and return another one. `(Int Int Int)` is not a legal Haskell type (since `Int` is a concrete type and not a type constructor, like `Maybe`).

Try:

```
data Bar = Bar (Int -> Int -> Int) Int Int
```

Your `doCalc` function is correct and will work with the new version.